# Google cloud create vm from image

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a problem with my vm on Google cloud.
I try to start a vm in java but i dont know how can I start a vm from an image. I mean how can I set to source image.
my code is:

```
    Instance instance = new Instance();

    compute.machineTypes();
    String machine = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/g1-small";
    instance.setMachineType(machine);

    String name = "newinstance";
    instance.setName(name);
    List<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = new ArrayList<NetworkInterface>();
    NetworkInterface iface = new NetworkInterface();
    iface.setName("eth0");

    iface.setNetwork("https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/networks/default");
    networkInterfaces.add(iface);
    instance.setNetworkInterfaces(networkInterfaces);

    Disk disk = new Disk();
    disk.setSizeGb(10L);
    disk.setName("mydisk");


    Compute.Disks.Insert insDisk = compute.disks().insert(projectId, zoneName, disk);
    insDisk.execute();

    AttachedDisk diskToInsert = new AttachedDisk();
    diskToInsert.setBoot(true);
    diskToInsert.setType("PERSISTENT");
    diskToInsert.setMode("READ_WRITE");
    diskToInsert.setDeviceName("newinstancedisk");
    diskToInsert.setSource("https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-a/disks/" + disk.getName());

    List<AttachedDisk> listOfDisks = new ArrayList<AttachedDisk>();
    listOfDisks.add(diskToInsert);

    instance.setDisks(listOfDisks);

    Compute.Instances.Insert ins = compute.instances().insert(projectId, zoneName, instance);
    Operation op = ins.execute();
    System.out.println(op.toPrettyString());
    System.out.println(instance.toPrettyString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the option 'disks[].initializeParams.sourceImage' where you can provide the full URL to the image used to create the root disk.

Take a look at these links [instances](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/insert), [starting an instance in the API](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#listing_all_images) and [startin an instance from an image](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#starting_an_instance_from_an_image) and [Instances](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances). In the last link you can see the value you can provide for disks[].initializeParams.